Use moving window to calculate the pairwise partial correlations between multi raster layers in R
Now I have three raster data, named y, x1, and x2. I want to use a moving window to create a 5X5 window to calculate partial correlation coefficients. The final results will return the partial correlation coefficients and corresponding P-values of y and x1, as well as the partial correlation coefficients and corresponding P-values of y and x2. I found the focal function in the Terra extension package, but I don't know how to use it to complete partial correlation analysis. Thank you very much for your help.
> library(terra)
> r <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))  
> names(r) <- c("y","x1","x2")
> r
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 77, 101, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : Cartesian (Meter) 
source      : logo.tif 
colors RGB  : 1, 2, 3 
names       :   y,  x1,  x2 
min values  :   0,   0,   0 
max values  : 255, 255, 255


> rfun <- function(r) {
+   d <- na.omit(data.frame(r))
+   if (nrow(d) < 25) {
+     c(NA,NA)
+   }else{
+     pm <- ppcor::pcor.test(d[,1],d[,2],d[,3])
+     c(pm$estimate,pm$p.value)
+   }
+ }
> terra::focal(r,w = c(5,5),fun = rfun)
error: [focal] test failed

I used the focal function to generate a moving window of 5X5. Based on this, I used the pixel elements in the third row and third column of each raster data as the focus to calculate the partial correlation coefficient. However, I found that the results obtained using the following three methods were not the same. Thank you very much for your help！
> set.seed(20241001)
> r1 <- rast(matrix(runif(100),10,10))
> r2 <- rast(matrix(runif(100),10,10))
> r3 <- rast(matrix(runif(100),10,10))
> r <- c(r1,r2,r3) %>% 
+   setNames(c("y","x1","x2"))

####Method 1####
> y <- r$y[1:5,1:5]
> x1 <- r$x1[1:5,1:5]
> x2 <- r$x2[1:5,1:5]
> pm <- ppcor::pcor.test(x = x1,y = y,z = x2)
> pm$estimate
[1] -0.2674145
> pm$p.value
[1] 0.2064882

####Method 2####
> y <- focalValues(x = r$y,w = 5,row = 3,nrow = 1)[3,]
> x1 <-focalValues(x = r$x1,w = 5,row = 3,nrow = 1)[3,]
> x2 <- focalValues(x = r$x2,w = 5,row = 3,nrow = 1)[3,]
> ppcor::pcor.test(x1,y,x2)
    estimate   p.value statistic  n gp  Method
1 -0.2674145 0.2064882 -1.301691 25  1 pearson


####Method 3####
> f <- terra::focalReg(r, w=5, fun=rfun)
> f
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 10, 10, 2  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 10, 0, 10  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. :  
source(s)   : memory
names       :       lyr1,      lyr2 
min values  : -0.2466887, 0.2452043 
max values  :  0.2276802, 0.9039822 
> # estimate 
> as.matrix(raster(f$lyr1))[3,3]
[1] 0.04691788
> # p.value
> as.matrix(raster(f$lyr2))[3,3]
[1] 0.8276637


Have a look at ?terra::layerCor, and discuss.  with fun = cor which gives you Pearson without resort to data.frame.

Thanks,Chris, but what I want to do is partial correlation analysis, not paired correlation analysis. This function can only perform paired correlation analysis, so I'm afraid it won't be helpful to me.

You may be able to use terra::focalReg for this
library(terra)
r <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))  
names(r) <- c("y","x1","x2")

rfun <- function(y, x, ...) {
   d <- na.omit(data.frame(y, x))
   # the ncol==2 test is to avoid a bug in testing to find the output number of layers 
   if ((ncol(d) == 2) | (nrow(d) < 25)) {  
     c(NA, NA)
   }else{
     pm <- ppcor::pcor.test(d[,1], d[,2], d[,3])
     c(pm$estimate,pm$p.value)
   }
}

f <- focalReg(r, w=5, fun=rfun)


Mr. Robert Hijmans, thank you very much for your reply. I have re edited my efforts over the past few hours in the question section. I have noticed that your answer does not match my understanding of how to use the focla function to calculate partial correlation coefficients. You can take a look at my latest editor. Thank you in advance for your answer.
